# $E(\max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\})$ is increasing in n for iid random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

How can I show that $E(X_{max})$ is increasing in $n$, where $X_{max} = max \{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$, and $X_i$'s are $iid$ draws from a distribution with cdf $F(.)$ and pdf $f(.)$ and with support $X_i \in [0, B]$.

Since $X_{max}$ has cdf $F_{max} = F^n$, I tried to show that $$E(X_{max})= \int_0^B{zdF_{max}(z)} = \int_0^B{znF^{n-1}(z)f(z)dz}$$ has a positive first derivative w.r.t $n$: $$\frac{d}{dn}E(X_{max}) = \int_0^B{zF^{n-1}(z)\Big(1+n\ln(F(z))\Big)f(z)dz}.$$
I am stuck here since $ln(F(z))$ can be hugely negative.

Maybe there is another way of tackling the problem which avoids taking derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $M_n=\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. Then
$$ M_{n+1}=\max\{M_n,X_{n+1}\}\geq M_n $$
and so
$$ \mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}]\geq \mathbb{E}[M_n]. $$

Comment: I though the same. But (small nuisance) perhaps she/he needs to prove that it's strictly increasing.

Comment: Then it is just a simple matter of observing that $X_{n+1}>M_n$ with positive probability.

Comment: @carmichael How can I generalise it to the case where $E(M'_{n+1}) \ge E(M_n)$, where $M'_n = max\{X_1', \ldots, X_n'\}$, and $X_i'$s are another independent draw from the same population. To put it differently, first you draw an iid sample of size n and then independently, you draw another sample of size n+1 (from the same population). Can one say the mean of the max in the second draw is greater than the the one of the first draw?

Comment: Yes: since the $X_i^{\prime}$ have the same distribution as the $X_i$, it follows that $\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}^{\prime}]=\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}]\geq \mathbb{E}[M_n]$.

Comment: @carmichael561 thank you for the help.